# How to define a function to read a wordlist

Tags: lisp, newlisp

I want to read a file which contains a list of words (one word per line) into a list.

```
(define (read-wordlist myFile)
  (begin 
   (set 'listA '()) 
   (set 'in-file (open myFile "read")) 
   (while (read-line in-file) 
       (set 'listA (append listA (list (current-line))))) 
   (close in-file)))
```

This function reads the file into a list `listA`

Assuming I have in `wordlist.txt`

```
Lemon
Orange
Lime
Mango
Pawpaw
Strawberry
Apple
Watermelon
Banana
```

I get

```
> (read-my-file "wordlist.txt")
true
> listA
 ("Lemon" "Orange" "Lime" "Mango" "Pawpaw" "Strawberry" "Apple" "Watermelon" "Banana")
```

### 2 parameters

I now want to have a function which reads the file into a list where I can specify the name.

```
(define (read-wordlist2 myFile myList)
  (begin
    (set myList '())
    (set 'in-file (open myFile "read")) 
      (while (read-line in-file) 
         (set myList (append myList (list (current-line)))))
    (close in-file)))
```

However the call

```
 (read-wordlist2 "wordlist.txt" 'myWordList)
```

gives the error

```
ERR: array, list or string expected in function append : myWordList
called from user defined function read-my-file2
```

How do I change the definition of `read-wordlist2` to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quoting your lists:

```
(define (read-wordlist2 myFile myList)
  (begin
    (set 'myList '())
    (set 'in-file (open myFile "read"))
      (while (read-line in-file)
         (set 'myList (append myList (list (current-line)))))
    (close in-file)))
```

But also there are probably much better ways to do this. `read-file` is useful here. [`extend`](http://www.newlisp.org/downloads/newlisp_manual.html#extend) and `push` are better ways to add to lists. And contexts provide dictionary and hash features which are generally faster and more useful.

Slightly more idiomatic would be:

```
(define (read-wordlist my-file)
    (let ((in-file  (open my-file "read"))
           my-list '())
      (while (read-line in-file)
          (extend my-list (list (current-line))))
      (close in-file)
      my-list))

(set 'word-list (read-wordlist "/tmp/wordlist.txt"))
```

More straightforward:

```
(set 'word-list (parse (read-file "/tmp/wordlist.txt") "\n" 0))
```

**Reference**: [parse](http://www.newlisp.org/downloads/newlisp_manual.html#parse)

Comment: The call `(read-wordlist2 "wordlist.txt" 'listOfFruits)` gives back `true`.  But `listOfFruits` is then `nil`. (Evaluated in newLisp)

Comment: Yes, your function is successful. But you'll be better off returning the value of `myList` at the end of the function, otherwise it will be discarded; it's local to the function definition. If you want to pass symbols by reference, use [contexts](http://www.newlisp.org/downloads/newlisp_manual.html#pass_big).

Comment: What does the third parameter of `parse` which is 0 mean?

Comment: Just my habit of using regular expressions to parse text, sorry... :)